# one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

```
public static int[,] operator *(int[,] arr1, int[,] arr2)
    {
        int sum;
        int[,] res = new int[arr1.GetLength(0), arr2.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < arr1.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    sum = sum + (arr1[i, k] * arr2[k, j]);
                }
                res[i, j] = sum;
                //Console.Write("{0} ", res[i, j]);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine();
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Here i am trying to overload * operator to multiply two matrices..
but the compiler keeps on showing me the error that..

" one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type c#"

please tell me what is the problem in my code and how to solve it..

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly the problem - you're not allowed to overload arbitrary operators like that... you can only overload operators where one of the operands (or the return type for a conversion) is the type  in which you're declaring the operator

Comment: I have to admit I was initially puzzled like OP was, as coming from C++ (think free functions). But found out that C# is not as permissive as C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler is already telling you what is wrong - but to quote section 7.3.2 of the C# 5 specification:

> User-defined operator declarations always require at least one of the parameters to be of the class or struct type that contains the operator declaration. Thus, it is not possible for a user-defined operator to have the same signature as a predefined operator.

In other words, it would be fine to have:

```
class Foo
{
    public static int[,] operator *(int[,] arr1, Foo arr2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

... because then the second operand is the declaring type. But in your case both of the operands are `int[,]`.

What you *could* do is add an extension method instead:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static int[,] Times(this int[,] arr1, int[,] arr2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could have:

```
int[,] x = ...;
int[,] y = ...;
int[,] z = x.Times(y);
```

Another solution - a better one, IMO, would be to declare your own `Matrix` class to encapsulate matrix operations. Then you *can* define your own multiplication operator:

```
public static Matrix operator *(Matrix left, Matrix right)
```

... and you're not interfering with `int[,]` arrays which aren't intended to be treated as matrices.

Comment: I came here for exactly this answer, but to be fair it's easy to read the error as it thinking that neither arr1 or arr2 as being an int[,] (the containing type).  I get what it means now, but I would say that the compiler is precisely NOT saying what the actual issue is with any clarity.  arr1 and arr2 are BOTH the containing type: int[,].

Comment: @JesseWilliams: I personally think it's fairly clear that "the containing type" is "the type containing the operator", which *isn't* `int[,]`. In what way is `int[,]` a "containing" type in this case?

Comment: It makes sense, once you understand it - it's just easy to misunderstand it.  Obviously "Containing" refers to the class that the declaration is currently in.  But, at least in light of how these errors are typically written, it's easy to see this as relating to the return type rather than the parent class.  Yes, if they meant return type they'd say return type - I agree.  But for something that you don't normally do, it's simple to misunderstand.  /shrug  Easy enough to resolve, though.