# how to make Vector3 * Vector3 (*) operator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to do * operator but i cant any one can help me create one ?

```
 public static Vector3 Move(Vector3 pos, Vector3 facing, Vector3 VC)
    {
        Vector3 W = VC;
        float angle = Angle(VC, facing);
        bool C = ClockWise(VC, facing);
        VC = RotatRadians(VC, angle, C);
        if (W.y < 0)
        {
            return pos + (VC * new Vector3(1, -1, 1));
         //ERROR: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'    
        }
        return pos + VC;
    }

public override static Vector3 operator *(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) => new Vector3(a.x * b.x, a.y * b.y, a.z * b.z);
     //ERROR: one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158771/1048799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload an operator for another existing class. One of the operands must be the class where it is defined. Hence, since `Vector3` is not written by you but part of Unity, you cannot override any binary operator using two `Vector3`.

see this Q&A for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158771/479251

You can simply create a static method or an extension method like `PointWiseProduct`.

And it happens that [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html%60) is already doing this.

Answer (score 4):

[Vector3.Scale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html)

> Multiplies two vectors component-wise.
> Every component in the result is a component of a multiplied by the same component of b.

Comment: I wonder why Unity doesn't implement the * operator as a scale.

Comment: @rfmodulator only them know exactly why, but I can say it would be quite confusing when used to linear algebra.

Comment: @Pac0 vector * vector is well defined as scaling... and that comment was somewhat rhetorical

Comment: @rfmodulator  `vector * vector` could be interpreted as dot product or a cross product or the "component wise" product, so I totally agree with the decision of not implementing a custom `*` operator to force the developers to call the appropriate method.

Comment: @Hellium Good enough for me.